# How to EF.Property<T> method works with included queries

Tags: entity-framework-core

I trying write a generic method for create response to datatables ajax request;

```cs
public static Response<T> CreateResponse<T>(IQueryable<T> query, Request request) where T : class
{
    query = query.AsNoTracking();
    var filtered = query;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Search.Value))
    {
        var keywords = Regex.Split(request.Search.Value, @"\s+").ToList();
        request
            .Columns
            .Where(p => p.Searchable)
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(c =>
                keywords.ForEach(k =>
                {
                    filtered = filtered.Intersect(query.Where(p => EF.Functions.Like(EF.Property<string>(p, c.Name), $"%{k}%")));
                })
            );
    }
    var ordered = filtered;
    request.Order.ForEach(p => ordered = p.Dir == "asc" ? ordered.OrderBy(q => EF.Property<T>(q, request.Columns[p.Column].Name)) : ordered.OrderByDescending(q => EF.Property<T>(q, request.Columns[p.Column].Name)));

    var paged = ordered.Skip(request.Start).Take(request.Length);

    return new Response<T> { draw = request.Draw, recordsTotal = query.Count(), recordsFiltered = filtered.Count(), data = paged.ToList() };
}
```

My problem is, when query parameter is `IIncludableQueryable` EF.Property method can't **locate sub properties.** For example;

```cs
DataTables.CreateResponse<Rayon>(context.Rayons.Include(p=>p.User), parameters);
```

`EF.Property<T>.Property<string>(p, "Name")` is working but, `EF.Property<T>.Property<string>(p, "User.Name")` is not working, exception message is "EF.Property called with wrong property name."

Sorry for bad English.

Comment: EF.Property<T> is a bug, you have to specify property type but not Entity type.

Comment: Thanks #svyatoslav-danyliv, but problem is here EF.Functions.Like(EF.Property<string>(p, c.Name) , it is property type

Comment: Check this issue https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/17099